# Problem using google Maps on GWT

Tags: java, google-maps, gwt

I am trying to use the latest jar of google-maps-api-v3 on GWT by following [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-maps-v3/wiki/GettingStarted) step by step but when I try to use it in my application, I got this exception :

```
    Loading modules
   ht.haitidataservices.simplemap.SimpleMap
      Loading inherited module 'com.google.gwt.maps.Maps'
         [ERROR] Unable to find 'com/google/gwt/maps/Maps.gwt.xml' on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?
      [ERROR] Line 5: Unexpected exception while processing element 'inherits'
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:262)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefSchema$BodySchema.__inherits_begin(ModuleDefSchema.java:495)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:230)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:274)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:331)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:402)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:280)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:308)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:979)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:436)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1045)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
      [ERROR] Failure while parsing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.DefaultSchema.onHandlerException(DefaultSchema.java:58)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.Schema.onHandlerException(Schema.java:66)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.HandlerMethod.invokeBegin(HandlerMethod.java:240)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.startElement(ReflectiveParser.java:274)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:331)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:402)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:280)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:308)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:979)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:436)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1045)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
      [ERROR] Unexpected error while processing XML
com.google.gwt.core.ext.UnableToCompleteException: (see previous log entries)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:355)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser$Impl.access$100(ReflectiveParser.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.util.xml.ReflectiveParser.parse(ReflectiveParser.java:402)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.nestedLoad(ModuleDefLoader.java:280)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader$1.load(ModuleDefLoader.java:192)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.doLoadModule(ModuleDefLoader.java:308)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.ModuleDefLoader.loadFromClassPath(ModuleDefLoader.java:151)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.loadModule(DevModeBase.java:979)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.loadModule(DevMode.java:548)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartup(DevMode.java:436)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:1045)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:804)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:309)
[ERROR] shell failed in doStartup method
```

It seems it's a module problem, saying that it cannot find `com/google/gwt/maps/Maps.gwt.xml`. I don't understand since I follow the tutorial and I am sure that what I am doing is correct. 
How can I solve this problem ? Thanks for your help

I am currently developping on JDK 1.6 with Eclipse Indigo on 64-bit Windows 7 system.

[EDIT] For precision, i added the google-maps jar in my application CLASSPATH and added the inherits line in my module file :

```
<module rename-to='egliseenquete'>
  <!-- Inherit the core Web Toolkit stuff.                        -->
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.user.User'/>
  <inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps' />
    ....
   </module>
```

[EDIT] I added the maps gwt jar on my CLASSPATH now I get this exception :

```
 12:27:28.703 [ERROR] [egliseenquete] Unable to load module entry point class ht.haitidataservices.egliseenquete.client.EgliseEnquete (see associated exception for details)

java.lang.RuntimeException: Deferred binding failed for 'com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl' (did you forget to inherit a required module?)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:53)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl.&lt;clinit&gt;(MapOptionsImpl.java:31)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.&lt;init&gt;(MapOptions.java:40)
    at ht.haitidataservices.egliseenquete.client.EgliseEnquete.buildMap(EgliseEnquete.java:100)
    at ht.haitidataservices.egliseenquete.client.EgliseEnquete.onModuleLoad(EgliseEnquete.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.JClassType, but class was expected
    at com.google.gwt.jsio.rebind.JSWrapperGenerator.generate(JSWrapperGenerator.java:276)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generate(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:48)
    at com.google.gwt.core.ext.GeneratorExtWrapper.generateIncrementally(GeneratorExtWrapper.java:60)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.StandardGeneratorContext.runGeneratorIncrementally(StandardGeneratorContext.java:681)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.cfg.RuleGenerateWith.realize(RuleGenerateWith.java:41)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle$Rebinder.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:74)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.StandardRebindOracle.rebind(StandardRebindOracle.java:285)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ShellModuleSpaceHost.rebind(ShellModuleSpaceHost.java:141)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebind(ModuleSpace.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.rebindAndCreate(ModuleSpace.java:455)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.GWTBridgeImpl.create(GWTBridgeImpl.java:49)
    at com.google.gwt.core.client.GWT.create(GWT.java:98)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.client.impl.MapOptionsImpl.&lt;clinit&gt;(MapOptionsImpl.java:31)
    at com.google.gwt.maps.client.MapOptions.&lt;init&gt;(MapOptions.java:40)
    at ht.haitidataservices.egliseenquete.client.EgliseEnquete.buildMap(EgliseEnquete.java:100)
    at ht.haitidataservices.egliseenquete.client.EgliseEnquete.onModuleLoad(EgliseEnquete.java:94)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:193)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:510)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:352)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How can I achieve this problem? Thx for help !!!

Comment: have entered ' <inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps' />' in your own application module and have made sure maps jar is in fact your class path.Are you using eclipse how did you add it your class path

Comment: I created a lib folder and add the jar in it. And after that, I have added the jar in the CLASSPATH

Comment: I tried with 'version gwt-maps3-0.2b\' worked for me . What is the version of this jar file you are using ? Also which version of GWT are you using? having asked these questions I do not think version will be the issue it is just not present in GWT class path in my opinion

Comment: Thx for your comment. I am currently using the 2.3 version of GWT and the same jar as you. Just one question, if I try to put the jar in the WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory, should it work? Or can I make sure that the library is on the GWT CLASSPATH?

Comment: Yes that exactly right First, copy these jars to the war/WEB-INF/lib directory of your project.Then, from Eclipse, right-click on each of these files and select Build Path > Add to Build Path. Not trying to be mean but I would strongly recommend creating a few dummy projects e.g. play around with google GIN and get used to GWT setup before going any further . Let me know how you go.

Answer (score 4):

I was having a similar problem.

I ended up using [this](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-google-apis/wiki/MapsGettingStarted) tutorial and it worked great. It is using gwt-maps-1.1.1.zip (Release date for this is much more recent for this one) and the latest GWT.

One thing to note, is that if you are looking at both tutorials to make sure you use:

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.GoogleMaps' />
```

and not

```
<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.Maps' />
```

as they have changed the file name in the com.google.gwt.map package of the jar file.

I suspect that if you check the filename in the com.google.gwt.map package of the map jar file, that the file name you were using to inherit is off. Then changing that line to what I suggested should fix it.

Hopefully this helps!

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

After looking inside of the jar file, I noticed that the path inheritance is incorrect for the xml file.

<inherits name='com.google.gwt.maps.GoogleMaps' /> --Is wrong path

<inherits name='com.google.maps.gwt.GoogleMaps' /> --Is correct path

Many hours wasted figuring this out, but this is the solution. Google made a mistake on their tutorial in this respect.

Comment: @Stephen, use &lt; to escape opening angle brackets; otherwise the content gets hidden, as here.